# Android: Keep listening for location update

Tags: android, location

I want to keep listening for location update even when my app destroyed (or closed), do i have to run a service for this? and what is the best practice's for continuous location update other than the ones [described here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/location/obtaining-user-location.html).

Comment: Well, you probably want to do something with the result? What are you trying to do when the location does change? Store it somewhere? Start an intent?

Comment: Probably send it to the server using an http post.

Comment: Then you will need a service, and you'll need a WAKE_LOCK. I should mentione that this will be a massive battery drain.

Comment: i know ! thats why im trying to find the best way to not drain the battery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your **application** is destroyed by the OS then it won't do anything. **Activities** and **Services** can both be killed by the OS if needed. Furthermore, unless you request a **WAKE_LOCK** you won't get updates if the phone enters sleep either.

Having said that, yes, you want to create a `Service` that implements `locationListener` and respond appropriately to `onLocationChanged()`. That way, the app will still receive the updates in the background.

Answer (score 2):

Even better you can use this:
public void addProximityAlert (double latitude, double longitude, float radius, long expiration, PendingIntent intent)

The intent will be fired even if the app is not running via broadcast.  Take the broadcast start a serviceintent to run your code.  The service will die when it is done.

Answer (score 0):

Yes using a service is the only safe way to continuously monitor location after your application is destroyed. It can be adventageous to persist your location info to an SQLite DB or flat file for reading the location information back out as binding to services can take some time.